# ffmpeg does not stram audio from rtsp to youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, streaming, youtube

I use my Raspberry 3 to stream my rtsp camera to youtube. But I don't have audio in the youtube stream...

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512 -re -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport udp  \
        -thread_queue_size 512k  -i rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.31:554/0/av0  \
        -framerate 13  -bufsize 4096k  -b:v 2000k -threads 4 \
        -q:v 3  -c:v h264_omx -bf 2 -r 25 -strict experimental -c:a aac \
        -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXX-XXX
```

The rtsp stream has some audio that I can hear with vlc. And I think ffmpeg decode and encode the audio input. Here is the result of the command

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-03-29-72be5d4 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-mmal --enable-libfreetype --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 77.101 / 58. 77.101
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
[udp @ 0x28e8d50] attempted to set receive buffer to size 393216 but it only ended up set as 327680
[udp @ 0x28f8fe0] attempted to set receive buffer to size 393216 but it only ended up set as 327680
[udp @ 0x2909aa0] attempted to set receive buffer to size 393216 but it only ended up set as 327680
[udp @ 0x2919de0] attempted to set receive buffer to size 393216 but it only ended up set as 327680
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.1 : mono
Input #1, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.31:554/0/av0':
  Metadata:
    title           : h264.mp4
    comment         : TAS-Tech Live Cast
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 11.92 fps, 12.50 tbr, 90k tbn, 23.75 tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (h264_omx))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264_omx @ 0x29406a0] Using OMX.broadcom.video_encode
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXX-XXX-XXX':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.42.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (h264_omx) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 2000 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.77.101 h264_omx
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) ([10][0][0][0] / 0x000A), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.77.101 aac
frame= 4968 fps= 12 q=-0.0 size=   52911kB time=00:06:58.64 bitrate=1035.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=   1x
```

What Can I change to have audio  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had copy ffmpeg from the internet and I was not understanding everything ! 
I just have to remove
`-f lavfi -i anullsrc`

Answer (score 1):

You're telling it to use the silent audio generated by the anullsrc filter instead of the audio from your main input. Use:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 512k -rtsp_transport udp -i rtsp://admin:@192.168.1.31:554/0/av0 -bufsize 4096k -b:v 2000k -c:v h264_omx -bf 2 -r 25 -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/XXXX-XXX
```

Unrelated changes:

- `-b:v` and `-q:v` are mutually exclusive. Only use one. I'm not familiar with h264_omx, but I don't know if it supports `-q:v` or ignores it.
- If you want to change the output frame rate use the `-r` option or the [fps filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps), not the `-framerate` option. The `-framerate` option is an input option used by certain demuxers.
- `-strict experimental` used to be needed to encode AAC audio, but that was changed in 2015, so remove it.
- The `-maxrate` option should be added when streaming.